# How do I access liferays database

Tags: database, liferay

I need to access my local liferays database via sql. How do I open a sql command prompt to this database?

Comment: I don't know. I downloaded and installed the liferay bundle with tomcat. So I use the default one.

Comment: So it seems to be hsql: http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Database+Configuration. Depending on configuration the DB may only exist in memory. You may also have a look at http://hsqldb.org/.

Comment: I don't think the db only exists in memory. If that would be the case all my changes I made in liferay would be lost.

Comment: The DB is called "in memory db", but nevertheless is stored in the file system - check out koeckc's answer. The default database is good for demo purposes, but you definitely want to change it to a proper "real" database for production

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start to [use a custom database](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Database+Configuration). Having all in a let's say *Mysql* database allows you to use all tools available for browsing that database. I think there exists many good tools for *Mysql* and that way you'll get what you want - easily and without much pain!

Answer (score 3):

I'll describe MySQL database installation.

First of all, you should download that database from official website :

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/

Than you should create (or change the existing one) file "proper-ext.properties" in your liferay folder. Delete all text in that file and paste this:

```
jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/lportal?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false
jdbc.default.username=root
jdbc.default.password=admin
```

Also you must create new user (root, admin) and new database and name it "lportal" (create database lportal).

After that, you should open you command line and enter `mysqld --console`. Then you should open another one command line and enter `mysql -u root -p`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Default a HSQL datbase is used (http://hsqldb.org/) (maybe there is aclient to connect to it)
Data is store in $LIFERAY_HOME\data\hsql
If you want a different db checkout:
http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Database+Portal+Properties

Comment: SquirrelSQL or any JDBC client can connect. With the default Liferay settings from the bundle you can only connect to HSQL with one DB client at a time so you need to stop Liferay if you want to connect Squirrel.

Comment: Now that you know where the data is stored, be warned: You don't state why you "need" access to the database. If it's for write access (e.g. you want to change data in it), then you actually *don't want it*. You *want* write access through Liferay's Service API. Unless you *only* change trivial things, the odds are that you'll mess up with the content so that the services will run into problems sooner or later. This holds especially for import jobs